# How to Insert tags in texts

Tags: python

I have a text like that

Or like that

I want to insert tags into them:

```
<tag1>I have a text like that</tag1>
<tag1>Or like that</tag1>
```

how can I achieve this in python ?

Comment: Paul, it looks like your question is missing some parts. Please correct it.

Comment: +1 No, no it is complete, self-referencing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds more like you want to insert text between tags. Right?

```
'<tag1>{0}</tag1>'.format('I have a text like that')
```

If it's a list of strings:

```
>>> l = ['I have a text like that', 'Or like that']
>>> ['<tag1>{0}</tag1>'.format(s) for s in l]
['<tag1>I have a text like that</tag1>', '<tag1>Or like that</tag1>']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just treat the tags as normal strings and do the string concatenation operation. That is the basic approach.

You can use `str.format` operation on string to insert text between tags in the string too.

But if your intention is to create a well formed XML Document, then Python provides a library called ElementTree

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element("root")
tag1 = ET.SubElement(root,"tag1")
tag1.text = "hi"
tag1 = ET.SubElement(root,"tag1")
tag1.text = "hello"
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('s.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, I have never done python, but what you may do is split each line using regex for a newline and store the lines in an array. Append the tags on each line and then combine them together using foreach loop...

Comment: I thought more or less this way, but it would be way too complicated for python facilities.

Comment: Regexps should be used to search for _patterns_. Simply searching for newlines or splitting text by them can and should be done with the builtin string functions.